# Bind different series in apex chart using vue.js for

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, charts, apexcharts

I'm trying to creare N different bar chart using a for in Vue.js, but obviously in this way I'm creating N chart with the same data series. I want to create this N chart binding different series in each chart.
I tried this way:

`<apexchart type="bar" height="100%" :options="chartOptionsRealTime" :series="seriesRealTime[0]"></apexchart>`

with series like:

```
seriesRealTime: [{
            name: 'first',
            data: [2.3, 3.1, 4.0, 10.1, 4.0, 3.6, 3.2, 2.3, 1.4, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2]
        },
        {
            name: 'second',
            data: [2.3, 3.1, 4.0, 10.1, 4.0, 3.6, 3.2, 2.3, 1.4, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2]
        },
        {
            name: 'second',
            data: [2.3, 3.1, 4.0, 10.1, 4.0, 3.6, 3.2, 2.3, 1.4, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2]
        }],
```

but `:series="seriesRealTime[0]"` doesn't work.

I want to create the firs chart with the series named "first", the second with the series named "second", ecc...
Thre is a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in documentation https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/series/

> Accepts an array of [name, data] object...

So you need to pass an array

```
<apexchart type="bar" height="100%" :options="chartOptionsRealTime" :series="[seriesRealTime[0]]"></apexchart>
```

Comment: perfect, but how do I increment the index of the series?

Comment: `<apexchart v-for="series in seriesRealTime" :key="series" type="bar" height="100%" :options="chartOptions" :series="[series]"></apexchart>`

Comment: Or like this
`<div v-for="series in seriesRealTime" :key="series"><apexchart type="bar" height="100%" :options="chartOptions" :series="[series]"></apexchart></div>`,
See Vue List Rendering